# Prevent SQL injection when queries have dynamically-generated/variable-length parameter lists

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sql-injection, pymysql

I am sorry for bad title but I have searched hours on web but I could not find anything.

Think about a user search performing with the text "this is good". I want to split text by spaces and make an SQL query with multiple "or ... like" depends on the count of word. It may be multiple. I've tried;

```
sub_query ""
search = "this is good"
split_by_space = search.split(" ")
for word in split_by_space:
    sub_query = sub_query + "content like '%{}%' or".format(word) #---> THIS IS NOT ESCAPED
sub_query = sub_query[0:-3] #---> to remove last ' or'
cursor.execute("select content from posts where %s",(sub_query))
```

This is not the right way of preventing SQL injection or prepared statement.

So, how to make prepared statement in Python/pymysql if I want to split words by spaces and perform search for every single word?

Comment: This is probably one of the best guides to prevent SQL injection. https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/

Comment: Tools like SQLAlchemy's query builder (which is usable completely independently of the ORM in the same package) will do this for you automatically (dynamically generating a query with placeholders, and an out-of-band set of values for those placeholders). I would suggest not reinventing the wheel, _especially_ as database drivers for Python's DB-API can use one of several interfaces, so being compatible requires supporting all the available conventions; SQLAlchemy already supports the entire set, so using it makes switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL/Oracle/whatever much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it safely:

```
search = "this is good"
split_by_space = search.split(" ")
terms = []
params = []
for word in split_by_space:
    terms.append("content like %s")
    params.append("%%{}%%".format(word)) 
query = "select content from posts where %s".format(" OR ".join(terms))
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

But you'll find that using `LIKE` with wildcards does not perform well. Using `LIKE` can make the query take *thousands* of times longer than using a fulltext index (depending on how many rows the table has). See my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).